# Error: Compiling RuleSet failed: Properties options are unknown

Tags: webpack, webpack-5

Having upgraded from webpack 4.46.0 to 5.45.1 I am encountering the following error during the build:

`Error: Compiling RuleSet failed: Properties options are unknown (at ruleSet[1].rules[6]: [object Object])`

Can someone clarify what exactly this error means? I can't work it out as it is so unsemantic. Do I need to set options? If so which?

It seems to point towards the settings in `module.rules`, but the 6th entry is just an array of loaders and has no options.

Previously these were loaded using the `loaders` property.

```
      module: {
        rules: [
          ...5 other entries...,
          {
            test: /\/custom-file.js$/,
            use: [
              'cache-loader',
              path.resolve(__dirname, '../build/package/custom-webpack-loader.js'),
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
```

Comment: Same issue here, did you find out something regarding this error?

Comment: Sadly not, I'm still currently on 4.46. As people often suggest with webpack, I think it will be a case of building the config file again from scratch

Answer (score 0):

[image]
Actually, you should look into the entry below this one, that is to say the 7th entry in reality.

In my case, I replaced `type: "url-loader"` with `type: "asset/resource"` without removing url-loader option, thus webpack complained about it. Since loading image&font is a breaking change in webpack-v5, I suppose perhaps its a common pitfall in most similiar upgrading cases.

--------More in detail:

I recreated my flawed config and tracked down the error emitted by webpack.

> Error: Compiling RuleSet failed: Properties options are unknown (at ruleSet[1].rules[4]: [object Object])
> at RuleSetCompiler.error (/Users/dearvikki/workspace/yapi/vendors/node_modules/webpack/lib/rules/RuleSetCompiler.js:381:10)
> at RuleSetCompiler.compileRule (/Users/dearvikki/workspace/yapi/vendors/node_modules/webpack/lib/rules/RuleSetCompiler.js:204:15)
> at /Users/dearvikki/workspace/yapi/vendors/node_modules/webpack/lib/rules/RuleSetCompiler.js:160:16
> at Array.map ()
> ...

It turns out that webpack will apply user-defined configs with extra default options, including an unshifted default ruleset, thats why the index of our ruleset become [1].

Calling backtrack:

[rules/RuleSetCompiler.js#L68](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/v5.74.0/lib/rules/RuleSetCompiler.js#L68)

```js
compile(ruleSet) {
    const rules = this.compileRules("ruleSet", ruleSet, refs);
}
```

[NormalModuleFactory.js#L239](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/v5.74.0/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js#L239)

```js
this.ruleSet = ruleSetCompiler.compile([
    {
        rules: options.defaultRules // default rules come first
    },
    {
        rules: options.rules // our rules
    }
]);
```

[config/normalization.js#L242](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/v5.74.0/lib/config/normalization.js#L242)

```js
const getNormalizedWebpackOptions = config => {
    ...
    module: nestedConfig(config.module, module => ({
        ...
        defaultRules: optionalNestedArray(module.defaultRules, r => [...r]),
    })
}
```

[webpack.js#L77](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/v5.74.0/lib/webpack.js#L77)

```js
const createCompiler = rawOptions => {
    const options = getNormalizedWebpackOptions(rawOptions);
    ...
    applyWebpackOptionsDefaults(options);
}
```

[config/defaults.js#L518](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/v5.74.0/lib/config/defaults.js#L518)

```js
// make default rules
A(module, "defaultRules", () => {
    return rules;
})
```

Comment: I only have 6 entries in the rules, so the 7th entry doesn't exist. Your fix is also rather specific to your case of using `url-loader`, so doesn't really answer the question

Comment: Thats weird since it mentioned rules[6].. it seems we can only let it go with the wind..: (

Comment: I'm also pretty sure that these errors index starting from 1, since the index of the ruleset is [1] and you can only have one set of rules defined in the config. Not really good behaviour since JS indexes from 0...

Comment: Your doubts actually motivated me to look more into webpack internal, and I hope my updates will answer the question that why the index of the ruleset is [1]! :P